# Cannot install Google SDK in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, libgdx, google-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install the Google Plugin for eclipse as described here: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.3

as I would like to set up a libgdx project. However, when I try to download it from this site:
 https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3

The SDK entries do not appear. I have seen a few questions about this but none of the solutions seems to have helped, though it is possible I am missing something. Why would the SDK options not appear when I look at this download site, when it seems like it should be expected?

These are the error I get:

```
The project 'my-gdx-game-html' does not have any GWT SDKs on its build path my-gdx-game-html
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project
```

I have also tried manually installing it using an archive of the download site but SDKs are also not available when I do that.

Comment: the same for me. I had to manually download SDKs.

Comment: Fair enough, I will do this now and hopefully it works, but I would love to know why it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed. There was a mistake when we deployed the GPE 4.3 update site. You should now be able to properly download SDKs from the GPE 4.3 Update Site.

Be sure to restart Eclipse before attempting to re-check the update site (otherwise you may get the cached version).

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it and it worked. And good time, I just logged into StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Download it separately, right here: https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.5.1.zip

Comment: I will do that and try it. Though I am still wondering why it does not work when I follow the instructions that others have obviously used.